# Setting update command on rc.local

Tags: raspbian, boot, pi-4, update, terminal

what will happen if I put my update and upgrade command on /etc/rc.local??

after reading some forums and all I understand that we can use crontab and so on. But what will happen if I do it in this way.

[image: rc.local]

Comment: Try it and see.  You don't need `sudo` in `rc.local`, when run at boot it is executed with root privileges.

Comment: Don't do that. Use apt automated updates. https://wiki.debian.org/UnattendedUpgrades

Answer (score 3):

`rc.local` gives you no guarantees that the network is available, so your command will likely fail without doing what you expect it to do.

There is a [proper way](https://www.zealfortechnology.com/2018/08/configure-unattended-upgrades-on-raspberry-pi.html) to get unattended upgrades working, which is configured in `/etc/apt` and activated by

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure --priority=low unattended-upgrades
```

Note that automatic updates work best when you also have automatic backups in place.

Answer (score 2):

My answer is offered in the spirit of [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle), and is this:

Don't try to automate your updates & upgrades - not in `rc.local`, not in `cron`, and not even in `systemd`. Why? As the bumper sticker says, "Shit Happens".

Also - there are times when a `reboot` is required to load a new kernel - not doing so can cause strange and errant behavior with some apps. Unfortunately, the system will not tell you when a kernel update was made, and so you either guess when it's needed, or you `reboot` after each `update && upgrade`. Some of the Debian distros have a `reboot-required` flag, but last I checked the Raspbian crowd hasn't ported this.

Automating `update && upgrade` is inviting trouble - trouble that may take much more time and effort to unwind than 100 manual `update && upgrade`.

If you want a notification or reminder to `update && upgrade` at a certain date & time, this can be arranged in numerous ways. If you want an *event-based* reminder, consider setting up `apt-listchanges` to send you a daily email (or redirect it to your `/etc/motd`).

Answer (score 1):

Do NOT put ANYTHING in rc.local - especially anything which is dependent on networking.

Automatic update is a bad idea as it sometimes prompts for user input.

If you REALLY need this for some remote application (I still think it is a bad idea) install unattended-upgrades.

Comment: AFAIK `apt-get` is smart enough not to ask anything when there's no input terminal. Granted, you'd still need to specify `-y`, otherwise it will likely just abort on the first question instead of assuming the answer is "Yes".